# Haskell Map for Trees

Tags: haskell, tree

My tree is defined by

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) 
        deriving (Show)
```

I also declare a testing tree.

```
myTree = Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 3)
```

What I want to do is create a function maptree f which will act on Leaf. To be more specifically, `f x = x +1`,

then `maptree f myTree` will return

```
Node (Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)) (Leaf 4)
```

My solution is

```
maptree f (Leaf a)= Leaf (f a)
maptree f (Node xl xr ) = Node (maptree xl) (maptree xr)
```

but it will return the following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Tree a'
       against inferred type `Tree t -> Tree t'
Probable cause: `maptree' is applied to too few arguments
In the first argument of `Node', namely `(maptree xl)'
In the expression: Node (maptree xl) (maptree xr)
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

However, if I do

```
maptree (Leaf a)= Leaf ( a + 1)
maptree (Node xl xr ) = Node (maptree xl) (maptree xr)
```

it does work out.

I can not see the difference between the first function and the second one. How do I get error? Thanks.

Comment: I got it working now. I'm stupid...><

Comment: Should be maptree f (Node  xl xr ) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr) instead of maptree f (Node  xl xr ) = Node (maptree  xl) (maptree  xr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One dumb way to not forget to pass along the function as you recurse deeper (for this sort of higher-order function) is to use a helper:

```
maptree f (Leaf a)     = Leaf (f a)
maptree f (Node xl xr) = Node (go xl) (go xr)
    where go = maptree f
```

Or, alternatively (and perhaps more commonly):

```
maptree f tree = go tree                      -- or eta reduce:   maptree f = go
    where go (Leaf a)     = Leaf (f a)
          go (Node xl xr) = Node (go xl) (go xr)
```

In the first example, I use `go` sort of as a macro for `maptree f`. In the second example, I take advantage of the fact that `maptree`'s input `f` is in scope inside the `go` function because `go` is declared in a `where` clause of `maptree`.

Answer (score 12):

You are missing the function on the recursive maptree calls:

```
maptree f (Leaf a)= Leaf (f a) 
maptree f (Node xl xr ) = Node (maptree xl) (maptree xr)
```

should be

```
maptree f (Leaf a)= Leaf (f a) 
maptree f (Node xl xr ) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr)
```

Answer (score 10):

Note that this is the obvious `fmap` of a `Functor` instance for your `Tree` type. You can therefore use the `DeriveFunctor` extension to have GHC generate it for you.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) 
    deriving (Functor, Show)
```

Let's try it.

```
*Main> fmap (+1) (Node (Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 3))
Node (Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)) (Leaf 4)
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message basically tells you what's wrong: you are not passing `maptree` enough arguments.  The definition `maptree f (Node xl xr)` says that `maptree` takes two arguments, a function and a tree.  But when you call it like `maptree xl`, you're only giving it one argument (a tree).

In your second version, you've defined `maptree` to only take one argument (a tree), which is why it doesn't produce that error.

You can fix your problem by, for example, calling `maptree f xl` instead of `maptree xl`.